# Using IExtractImage to create file thumbnails in Python

Tags: python, thumbnails, pywin32, windows-explorer

I am rewriting in Python (CherryPy web server on Windows 7) an old application that I wrote in VB6 long time ago.

My old application uses [this class](http://www.vbaccelerator.com/home/VB/Code/Libraries/Shell_Projects/Thumbnail_Extraction/Thumbnail_Extractor_Code.html) to extract the file thumbnails from CAD files, just as Windows Explorer does.

[This post](http://grokbase.com/t/python/python-win32/074jm9dv2g/how-to-use-iextractimage-in-python) addresses the problem, but doesn't show the working code and it is very old.

How do I use IExtractImage in Python?

EDIT:

I copied the little code from the old post, which follows the same steps as my old VB code. It crashes with the message `pywintypes.com_error: (-2147221164, 'Class not registered', None, None)` on the last line:

```
from win32com.shell import shell, shellcon
import pythoncom

def test_IExtractImage(path, filename):
    iSHFolder = shell.SHGetDesktopFolder()
    eaten, idList, attr = iSHFolder.ParseDisplayName(0, None, path)
    targetFolder = iSHFolder.BindToObject(idList, None, shell.IID_IShellFolder)
    eaten, targetIdList, attr = targetFolder.ParseDisplayName(0, None, filename)
    iidExtractImage = pythoncom.MakeIID('{BB2E617C-0920-11D1-9A0B-00C04FC2D6C1}')
    extractImage = targetFolder.GetUIObjectOf(0, [targetIdList], iidExtractImage, 0)

test_IExtractImage('c:\\', 'test.e2')
```

What are the missing steps to get the image and generate a file so that I can serve it on a web page?

Comment: You should play with python + win32/ctypes

Comment: Ever find a solution to this? I need to do the exact thing for CATIA files. Thanks!

Comment: @hansonap My solution has been working for 2 years with the python server calling an external .exe file to create the image. I created the .exe in vb6 using the example mentioned in the post. I just gave it another try and I noticed that the error I described is not thrown now. Perhaps because in 2014 I was using python 64 bits and now I'm using 32 bits, or perhaps because there is a better coverage. So I spent 30 minutes trying to get the next step done (`extractImage.GetLocation`), but without success.